# How can the develop-run cycle be made faster with server side blazor?

Tags: visual-studio-2019, blazor, blazor-server-side

I develop my first server side blazor app right now. I have a Visual Studio 2019 solution and I run it using "Start without Debugging". Then the webpage opens in the browser pointing to localhost.

Whenever I make changes to a .razor file and save it, the browser page displays "Attempting to reconnect" which I never saw to succeed, thus followed by the message to reload the page after some seconds. Reload also requires some seconds.

First question(s): How could I make attempting to reconnect succeed? Is there at timeout that is too short?

Usually this takes quite some time, so if I want to see how small changes to the UI will look like in the browser I have to go through several seconds of waiting for the refresh and the reconnection. This seriously slows down my productivity. I would want to be able to see changes rather fast so that I can prototype more quickly.

Second question(s): Is this a limitation of blazor? Is there a workaround?

Comment: What I do is that I don't start the application from VS it self. Instead I the terminal command with file change watcher. Each time something changes in the folder the compiler recompiles the source and runs it. It is not perfect but it helps.
The command is in the root folder of the application: dotnet watch run

Comment: @ZsoltBendes thx, I already tried that, but the problem is even worse. Using `dotnet watch run` instead of IIS there is no valid https certificate and most browsers prevent me from continuing https on localhost without a valid certificate. The HTTP URL gets upgraded to HTTPs all the time due to HSTS and you can deactivate that a hundred times over and over. Second, and most important there is no improvement over the actual cycle speed. The good thing is that you get to see the logs in the console.